# How to retain service settings through InstallShield upgrade install

Tags: windows-services, installation, installshield, installscript

I have an InstallScript project in IS2010.  It has a handful of services that get installed.  Some are C++ exes and use the "InstallShield Object for NT Services".  Others are Java apps installed as services with [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp) through LaunchAppAndWait command line calls.  Tomcat is also being installed as a service through a call to its service.bat.

When the installer runs in upgrade mode, the services are reinstalled, and the settings (auto vs. manual startup, restart on fail, log-on account, etc.) are reverted to the defaults.

I would like to save the service settings before the file transfer and then repopulate them afterward, but I haven't been able to find a good mechanism to do this.  How can I save and restore the service settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this working by reading the service information from the registry in OnUpdateUIBefore, storing it in a global variable, and writing the information back to the registry in OnUpdateUIAfter.

Code:

```
export prototype void LoadServiceSettings();
function void LoadServiceSettings()
number i, nResult;
string sServiceNameArray(11), sRegKey, sTemp;
BOOL bEntryFound;
begin
PopulateServiceNameList(sServiceNameArray);
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
//write service start values to the registry
for i = 0 to 10
    if (ServiceExistsService(sServiceNameArray(i))) then
        sRegKey = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\" + sServiceNameArray(i);
        nResult = RegDBSetKeyValueEx(sRegKey, "Start", REGDB_NUMBER, sServiceSettings(i), -1);
        if(nResult < 0) then
            MessageBox ("Unable to save service settings: " + sServiceNameArray(i) + ".", SEVERE);
        endif;
    endif;
endfor;
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT); //set back to default
end;

export prototype void SaveServiceSettings();
function void SaveServiceSettings()
number i, nType, nSize, nResult;
string sServiceNameArray(11), sRegKey, sKeyValue;
begin
PopulateServiceNameList(sServiceNameArray);
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
for i = 0 to 10
    if (ServiceExistsService(sServiceNameArray(i))) then
        //get service start values from registry
        sRegKey = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\" + sServiceNameArray(i);
        nResult = RegDBGetKeyValueEx(sRegKey, "Start", nType, sKeyValue, nSize);
        if(nResult < 0) then
            MessageBox ("Unable to save service settings: " + sServiceNameArray(i) + ".", SEVERE);
        endif;
        sServiceSettings(i) = sKeyValue;
    endif;
endfor;
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT); //set back to default
end;
```